# formik setFieldValue input struggling

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik

I have a form using Formik. Inside this form, there are multiple input fields, checkboxes, and similar components. I am passing Formik as props to each component like this:

```
<DescriptionField formik={formik} />
```

These components contain custom Material-UI input components.

In the onChange event, I am using setFieldValue like this:

```
export const DescriptionField = ({
    formik,
    ...rest
}: FormComponentProps<T>) => (
    <Field name="description">
        {({ form: { setFieldValue }}: FieldProps) => (
             <CustomInput
                value={formik.values.description}
                label="Description"
                setField={(description) => {
                   setFieldValue('description', description);
                }}
                {...rest}
            />
        )}
    </Field>
);


export const CustomInput = ({
    setField,
    values
    label
    ...rest
}: FormComponentProps<T>) => (
     <TextField
        onChange={(e: any) => {
            setField({ ...values, [selectedOption]: e.target.value });
        }}
        value={values && values[selectedOption] ? values[selectedOption] : ''}
       ....
    </TextField>
);
```

When typing in these components, there is a slight delay of 1-2 seconds before the input is filled.

I tried using useDebounce callback, which partially solved the issue, but what is the best way to handle this?

Comment: We'll need more information. But I'm guessing this "delay" that you're talking about happens when you're typing and causes rerender of your components, which lags out the UI. Perhaps you could isolate your component so it doesn't re-render needlessly affecting other components. But again, we'll need more context.